# plotting in Robinson projection in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, r-raster

I used the code I found online to make a basic map with Robinson projection in R. I'm not sure how to add my data onto it.

```
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)

(a <- ggplot(data = world) +
 geom_sf() + theme_bw() +
 coord_sf(crs = "+proj=robin +lon_0=0w"))
```

Let's call the data frame df.

I tried

```
(a <- ggplot(data = world) +
geom_sf() + theme_bw() +
geom_raster(
data = df,
aes(
  x=latitude,
  y=longitude,
  fill=tos
))  +
coord_sf(crs = "+proj=robin +lon_0=0w"))
```

but I get an error

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'latitude' not found

and I tried

```
a <- a + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="df"))
```

but I get an error

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_rect, x$x, x$y, x$width, x$height, resolveHJust(x$just, : invalid color name 'df'

When I look at names(df) I only get one with "layer"

if I just use `plot(df)` I get the actual map! but I want to plot it nicer in a Robinson projection, how do I do this?

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 300, 360, 108000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 0.6  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : -1.728468, 35.60058  (min, max)
```

Comment: It's helpful if you put any `library()` calls needed to run your code... I'm not sure where the `ne_countries()` function comes from, for example.

Comment: Also, this won't fix your problem but it will solve the next one: you generally want `x = longitude, y = latitude`, not vice versa.

Comment: What do you want to plot? We need a few rows of the table `df`. You you want to plot points on the maps? choropleth? Sth. else?